# Pass integer from one method to another

Tags: java, class, variables, methods

I am trying to pass three integers from one method to another method in the same class in Java.

My current code looks like this (but simplified):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class One()
{
    int var1 = 33;
    int var2 = 34;      //these three have to sum to 100
    int var3 = 33;

    //this is in a while loop in case the three numbers != 100
    public int two()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        //let user change var1, var2, var3 if they want
        if (var1 + var2 + var3 == 100)
        {
            //I would guess the code for passing the variables is here
            break;
        }
        //else statement
    }

    public int three()
    {
         //transfer var1, var2, var3 here and do stuff with it
    }
}
```

I have looked this up, and apparently I would have to make an object or an array to pass them into the other method(?). However, I feel like there is a simpler way to go about doing this as I only have two methods in my class.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.. You just want to acess var1 var2 and var3 in method three() ?

Comment: You can access the variables from method three() without any need to pass them as all the three variables are part of the class.

Comment: Yes I am, sorry I should have made that more clear

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class One()
{
    int var1 = 33
    int var2 = 34      //these three have to equal 100
    int var3 = 33

    //this is in a while loop incase the three numbers != 100
    public int two()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        //let user change var1, var2, var3 if they want
        if (var1 + var2 + var3 == 100)
        {
            three(var1,var2,var3); //call the method, supplying the 3 parameters
        }
        //else statement
    }

    public int three(int var1, int var2, int var3) //declare your method parameters
    {
         //transfer var1, var2, var3 here and do stuff with it
         return 0;//return an int
    }
```

Comment: Ok, so I did that in my program and the compiler has the error of identifier expected in the second method. Why is that?

Comment: In the method above you need to add a return value or you need to change the method to void.

Comment: Sorry, was a sloppy answer. Added Tiago's tip.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as follows:

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class One {

int var1 = 33;
int var2 = 34;      //these three have to equal 100
int var3 = 33;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public void two() {
    if (var1 + var2 + var3 == 100) {
        three(var1, var2, var3);
    }
    //else statement
}

public void three(int a, int b, int c) {
    //transfer var1, var2, var3 here and do stuff with it
    System.out.println(a);
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    new One().two();
}
}
```

Also,

1. Your class should not have round brackets , unlike methods
2. break statement is only allowed inside loops/switch,

Comment: 1) Your example doesn't compile.  2) An instance method should use the instance variables; if you are passing the values, make the method `static`. 3) `break` can be used inside a labeled block.

Comment: Well, I just wanted to show how to pass parameters to another method, I didn't try to compile it. I am not aware of the 2nd rule. Is that considered a best practice? As I have seen examples where you pass values to instance method and its not static.

Comment: Sorry for the sloppy code. I have edited it so that it compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Few points :

1. You read values but never use them ( so the condition will be always true ) but this is not the question.
2. keep in mind that when primitive types ( int ) is passed into a method : a COPY of the value is actually passed in. so changing var1 inside method two() will not change the field variable var1 ( the class variable )

Comment: Oh, you made me realize that my question is more of how can I change the field variable from inside a method. Right? Because If I can edit those variables then they can pass onto my second one?